# Palabra para designar «que resume»

Tags: solicitud-de-término

¿Existe algún adjetivo que indique que «su dedicación o su función principal consiste en resumir»?

La palabra «resumidor» no aparece en el DRAE

Buscaría un término lo más similar posible.

Comment: tanto *resumidor* como *resumiente* son opciones válidas.  Las terminaciones *-dor* y *-nte* son productivas en el castellano moderno, Eso dicho, aparte de una aplicación muy moderna, no veo que *resumidor* haya disfrutado de uso (pero en portugués se ha usado), mientras *resumiente* sí tiene algunos ejemplos históricos.

Comment: @user0721090601 Eso es una respuesta (y muy buena e interesante)

Comment: Alguien puede agregarlo como tal si quiere.  Ya dejé de colocar respuestas formales en este sitio.

Answer (score 2):

Entendemos [resumir](https://dle.rae.es/resumir?m=form) como la reducción de  algo (un texto, una historia una idea) a su versión esencial (`Reducir a términos breves y precisos, o considerar tan solo y repetir abreviadamente lo esencial de un asunto o materia.` )

No sé para qué aplicación estés buscando el término; si vaya a ser atribuido a una persona o proceso. Yo trataría de usar el adjetivo de algo o alguien que cumpla esa función sinónima (que abrevia  condensa, reduce, simplifica, extracta)

- abreviador
- condensador
- reductor
- simplificador
- extractor